# Convert String Value to User Defined Type

Tags: c#, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

Hi I want to convert string value to DataType so that i can use it. First i would like to describe my question.

1: I have Typed DataSet Named **Files**
   2: This DataSet Contains **6 DataTables**
   3: DataTables names are  (**File01**, **File02**, **File03**, **File04**, **File05**, **File06**)
   4: Now i want check dynamically that which DataTable to call and  create the instance of that class using **Reflection**.

```
string dataTableName = filename + "DataTable"; //This will generate File01DataTable,File02DataTable...,File06DataTable
Type dataTableType = typeof ( Files.File01DataTable ).Assembly.GetType( dataTableName );
```

5: Now create instance of that DataTable. Here tDS is TypedDataSet Files Instance

```
dataTableType dt = ( dataTableType )tDS.Tables[filename];
```

6:But above approch doesn't works. When i try to return the type it returns me null instead of that class. Can someone guide me please.
**Thanks in Advance**

**Edit:**
Well thanks [ronnie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2024891/ronnie) Because you solved my 50% of problem. Now When i get type here is the other scenario for instantiating object.

```
string dataTableName = filename + "DataTable";// It Generate File01DataTable and so on till File06DataTable.
```

Now When i want to instantiate the object at runtime i cann't tell it

```
File01DataTable dt = (File01DataTable) tDS.Table[filename];
```

instead i need generic object it should be decide at runtime which object to instantiate e.g File02DataTable or File05DataTable. So How can i overcome this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to use a **strongly typed** DataSet loosely typed?

Comment: Because it's my need...

Answer (score 1):

Is your class nested? If so you will need to add the '+' character between classes. In addition a fully referenced namespace is required to return the type.

```
namespace SO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dataTableName = "SO.Files+File01DataTable";
            Type dataTableType = typeof(Files.File01DataTable).Assembly.GetType(dataTableName);
            Files.File01DataTable dt = (Files.File01DataTable)Activator.CreateInstance(dataTableType);
        }
    }
}
```